# CakePHP - How can add more validate fields to an existed model?

Tags: cakephp

I have a Model

```
class Model extends AppModel {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->validate=array(

    'first_name' => array(
            'NotEmpty' => array(
                'rule'    => 'NotEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'message'=> 'Not empty'
            )
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'NotEmpty' => array(
                'rule'    => 'NotEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'message'=> 'Not empty'
            )
        ),
     );
    }
}
```

The problem is in view I have a dynamic data need to validation (last_name and firstname up to 30). How can I add them dynamical into Model and validate in Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [dinamically change validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules)

Make a new function in the model that will update your validation rules, as described in the documentation.

In the controller, before validating the model, call the model function that changes the validation rules.